# Show only some JSON arrays as output in ThingWorx

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, urlfetch, thingworx

I was trying to fetch the details when a PIN code is given and by executing it, I got an output like this:

```
{
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "formatted_address": "Karnataka 581110, India",
            "types": [
                "postal_code"
            ],
            "geometry": {
                "viewport": {
                    "southwest": {
                        "lng": 75.27469980000001,
                        "lat": 14.6612046
                    },
                    "northeast": {
                        "lng": 75.599386,
                        "lat": 14.8850042
                    }
                },
                "bounds": {
                    "southwest": {
                        "lng": 75.27469980000001,
                        "lat": 14.6612046
                    },
                    "northeast": {
                        "lng": 75.599386,
                        "lat": 14.8850042
                    }
                },
                "location": {
                    "lng": 75.41116439999999,
                    "lat": 14.7732552
                },
                "location_type": "APPROXIMATE"
            },
            "address_components": [
                {
                    "types": [
                        "postal_code"
                    ],
                    "short_name": "581110",
                    "long_name": "581110"
                },
                {
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_2",
                        "political"
                    ],
                    "short_name": "Haveri",
                    "long_name": "Haveri"
                },
                {
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        "political"
                    ],
                    "short_name": "KA",
                    "long_name": "Karnataka"
                },
                {
                    "types": [
                        "country",
                        "political"
                    ],
                    "short_name": "IN",
                    "long_name": "India"
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJ0dut9kpvuTsRk0SobKd72tU",
            "postcode_localities": [
                "Aladakatti",
                "Aladakatti",
                "Ashwini Nagar",
                "Bannihalli",
                "Basaveshwar Nagar",
                "Benakanahalli",
                "Bharadi",
                "Bhujruk Veerapur",
                "Bujruk Kodihalli",
                "Byagawadi",
                "Chikklingadalli",
                "Devagiri",
                "Devagiri Yallapura",
                "Devihosur",
                "Ganajur",
                "Gourapur-M-Adur",
                "Gourapura",
                "Guddad Mattihalli",
                "Hanumanahalli",
                "Haveri",
                "Hedigonda",
                "Hirelingadahalli",
                "Hombardi",
                "Hosalli",
                "Hosalli-m-adur",
                "Ingalagondi",
                "Jangamanakoppa",
                "Kabbur",
                "Kadamanahalli",
                "Kaginelli",
                "Kalagonda",
                "Kallapura",
                "Kallihal",
                "Kasambi",
                "Katenahalli",
                "Kengond",
                "Kerimattihalli",
                "Khurda Veerapura",
                "Kodihalli",
                "Kulenur",
                "Kummur",
                "Kurabagonda",
                "Malapur",
                "Mallur",
                "Manjunath Nagar",
                "Mulathalli",
                "Naganur",
                "Nagendranamatti",
                "Najikalakamapur",
                "Nelogal",
                "Sankripura",
                "Shiddeshwar Nagar",
                "Shivajinagar",
                "Shivalinganagar",
                "Somasagara",
                "Timakapur",
                "Timmapur-M-Adur",
                "Timmenhalli",
                "Totadayallapur",
                "Uppanshi",
                "Venkatapura",
                "Vidya Nagar",
                "Yattinahalli",
                "kanakapur",
                "kanavalli",
                "kuragund"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

But I only need

```
{
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_2",
                        "political"
                    ],
                    "short_name": "Haveri",
                    "long_name": "Haveri"
                },


 {
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        "political"
                    ],
                    "short_name": "KA",
                    "long_name": "Karnataka"
                }
```

this much only. So how can I show only these two?

Comment: What is a condition for a filter?

Answer (score 3):

***Observations:***

- The expected output is not valid JSON. It should be an array of objects.
- As you did not mention filter criteria: Hence, I am assuming/filtering the response based on the types containing sub string `administrative_area_level`.

***Solutions:*** You can iterate the API response by using [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with the help of [`String.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) methods to get the desired output.

Live Demo**:**

```js
const apiResponse = {
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "formatted_address": "Karnataka 581110, India",
            "types": [
                "postal_code"
            ],
            "geometry": {
                "viewport": {
                    "southwest": {
                        "lng": 75.27469980000001,
                        "lat": 14.6612046
                    },
                    "northeast": {
                        "lng": 75.599386,
                        "lat": 14.8850042
                    }
                },
                "bounds": {
                    "southwest": {
                        "lng": 75.27469980000001,
                        "lat": 14.6612046
                    },
                    "northeast": {
                        "lng": 75.599386,
                        "lat": 14.8850042
                    }
                },
                "location": {
                    "lng": 75.41116439999999,
                    "lat": 14.7732552
                },
                "location_type": "APPROXIMATE"
            },
            "address_components": [
                {
                    "types": [
                        "postal_code"
                    ],
                    "short_name": "581110",
                    "long_name": "581110"
                },
                {
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_2",
                        "political"
                    ],
                    "short_name": "Haveri",
                    "long_name": "Haveri"
                },
                {
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        "political"
                    ],
                    "short_name": "KA",
                    "long_name": "Karnataka"
                },
                {
                    "types": [
                        "country",
                        "political"
                    ],
                    "short_name": "IN",
                    "long_name": "India"
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJ0dut9kpvuTsRk0SobKd72tU",
            "postcode_localities": [
                "Aladakatti",
                "Aladakatti",
                "Ashwini Nagar",
                "Bannihalli",
                "Basaveshwar Nagar",
                "Benakanahalli",
                "Bharadi",
                "Bhujruk Veerapur",
                "Bujruk Kodihalli",
                "Byagawadi",
                "Chikklingadalli",
                "Devagiri",
                "Devagiri Yallapura",
                "Devihosur",
                "Ganajur",
                "Gourapur-M-Adur",
                "Gourapura",
                "Guddad Mattihalli",
                "Hanumanahalli",
                "Haveri",
                "Hedigonda",
                "Hirelingadahalli",
                "Hombardi",
                "Hosalli",
                "Hosalli-m-adur",
                "Ingalagondi",
                "Jangamanakoppa",
                "Kabbur",
                "Kadamanahalli",
                "Kaginelli",
                "Kalagonda",
                "Kallapura",
                "Kallihal",
                "Kasambi",
                "Katenahalli",
                "Kengond",
                "Kerimattihalli",
                "Khurda Veerapura",
                "Kodihalli",
                "Kulenur",
                "Kummur",
                "Kurabagonda",
                "Malapur",
                "Mallur",
                "Manjunath Nagar",
                "Mulathalli",
                "Naganur",
                "Nagendranamatti",
                "Najikalakamapur",
                "Nelogal",
                "Sankripura",
                "Shiddeshwar Nagar",
                "Shivajinagar",
                "Shivalinganagar",
                "Somasagara",
                "Timakapur",
                "Timmapur-M-Adur",
                "Timmenhalli",
                "Totadayallapur",
                "Uppanshi",
                "Venkatapura",
                "Vidya Nagar",
                "Yattinahalli",
                "kanakapur",
                "kanavalli",
                "kuragund"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
};

const result = apiResponse.results.map(({ address_components }) => {
    return address_components.filter(({ types }) => {
        return types.some(item => item.indexOf('administrative_area_level') !== -1)
    });
});

console.log(...result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pure JavaScript solution:

```js
console.log(
({
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "formatted_address": "Karnataka 581110, India",
            "types": [
                "postal_code"
            ],
            "geometry": {
                "viewport": {
                    "southwest": {
                        "lng": 75.27469980000001,
                        "lat": 14.6612046
                    },
                    "northeast": {
                        "lng": 75.599386,
                        "lat": 14.8850042
                    }
                },
                "bounds": {
                    "southwest": {
                        "lng": 75.27469980000001,
                        "lat": 14.6612046
                    },
                    "northeast": {
                        "lng": 75.599386,
                        "lat": 14.8850042
                    }
                },
                "location": {
                    "lng": 75.41116439999999,
                    "lat": 14.7732552
                },
                "location_type": "APPROXIMATE"
            },
            "address_components": [
                {
                    "types": [
                        "postal_code"
                    ],
                    "short_name": "581110",
                    "long_name": "581110"
                },
                {
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_2",
                        "political"
                    ],
                    "short_name": "Haveri",
                    "long_name": "Haveri"
                },
                {
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        "political"
                    ],
                    "short_name": "KA",
                    "long_name": "Karnataka"
                },
                {
                    "types": [
                        "country",
                        "political"
                    ],
                    "short_name": "IN",
                    "long_name": "India"
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJ0dut9kpvuTsRk0SobKd72tU",
            "postcode_localities": [
                "Aladakatti",
                "Aladakatti",
                "Ashwini Nagar",
                "Bannihalli",
                "Basaveshwar Nagar",
                "Benakanahalli",
                "Bharadi",
                "Bhujruk Veerapur",
                "Bujruk Kodihalli",
                "Byagawadi",
                "Chikklingadalli",
                "Devagiri",
                "Devagiri Yallapura",
                "Devihosur",
                "Ganajur",
                "Gourapur-M-Adur",
                "Gourapura",
                "Guddad Mattihalli",
                "Hanumanahalli",
                "Haveri",
                "Hedigonda",
                "Hirelingadahalli",
                "Hombardi",
                "Hosalli",
                "Hosalli-m-adur",
                "Ingalagondi",
                "Jangamanakoppa",
                "Kabbur",
                "Kadamanahalli",
                "Kaginelli",
                "Kalagonda",
                "Kallapura",
                "Kallihal",
                "Kasambi",
                "Katenahalli",
                "Kengond",
                "Kerimattihalli",
                "Khurda Veerapura",
                "Kodihalli",
                "Kulenur",
                "Kummur",
                "Kurabagonda",
                "Malapur",
                "Mallur",
                "Manjunath Nagar",
                "Mulathalli",
                "Naganur",
                "Nagendranamatti",
                "Najikalakamapur",
                "Nelogal",
                "Sankripura",
                "Shiddeshwar Nagar",
                "Shivajinagar",
                "Shivalinganagar",
                "Somasagara",
                "Timakapur",
                "Timmapur-M-Adur",
                "Timmenhalli",
                "Totadayallapur",
                "Uppanshi",
                "Venkatapura",
                "Vidya Nagar",
                "Yattinahalli",
                "kanakapur",
                "kanavalli",
                "kuragund"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}).results[0].address_components.filter(item => item.types.filter(tp => tp.indexOf("administrative_area_level") >= 0).length)
)
```

Explanation:

- the items are inside the `results` member
- this is a 1-itemed array, so we get its first and only item
- `address_components` is wrapped around the addresses
- we search for the appropriate address items
- by filtering the `types` by containing a type which contains `administrative_area_level`